# add custom header to collection view swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I am trying to add header to `collectionView` using custom xib file. I created the `xib` file with class implementing `UICollectionReusableView`.
In `collectionViewController` I registered the `xib` file like this:

```
self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: HCollectionReusableView.nibName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: HCollectionReusableView.reuseIdentifier)
```

and after that in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` I did

```
let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: HCollectionReusableView.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HCollectionReusableView
```

and for sizing

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
}
```

I am getting error: Could not load NIB in bundle.
any missing code ?

HCollectionReusableView class:

```
class HCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

static var nibName : String
    {
    get { return "headerNIB"}
}

static var reuseIdentifier: String
    {
    get { return "headerCell"}
}



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
```

}

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to call `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
           let reusableview = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath) as! HCollectionReusableView

            reusableview.frame = CGRect(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, headerHight)
         //do other header related calls or settups
            return reusableview


    default:  fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

This way you can initialise and show the header

Another way of setting the UICollectionViewHeader frame is by extending `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` like this:

```
extension UIViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100) //add your height here
    }
}
```

This removes the need to call :

```
reusableview.frame = CGRect(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width, headerHight)
```

in the above mentioned

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

> Remember to register the HeaderView after you initialise your `UICollectionView` by calling:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: HCollectionReusableView.nibName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HCollectionReusableView")
```

*Swift 4.1 Update*

`UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader` has been renamed to `UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader`

Comment: I think I have to change the registration of xib to class, here the error now: could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader with identifier HCollectionReusableView - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
(null)

Comment: you get the error since the identifiers when you deque the item and when you register don't match ... try to hardcode the identifier like this when you register the cell : `self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: HCollectionReusableView.nibName, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "HCollectionReusableView")
 ` this should work ... then you can just adjust the code to fit your needs

Comment: you will register class only if you don't use a Xib or Storyboard at all

Comment: great, save my day

Comment: You still need to register your class, not the nib, otherwise it won't type cast.
yourCollectionView.register(YourClassName.self,
            forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
            withReuseIdentifier: "YourHardCodeIdentifierString")

Answer (score 5):

```
final class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionReusableView.reuseIdentifierHeader)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 40)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionReusableView.reuseIdentifierHeader, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionReusableView
    header.setupView()
    
    return header
}
}

final class MyCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {

   static let reuseIdentifierHeader = "MyId"

   func setupView() {
      //Code...
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set File' Owner setting in your xib File? Change file owner to your View controller hosting collectionView.

[image]

Comment: yes I did, in file owner and in collection reusable view